# Print a Slider Output

Tags: javascript

I want to have the slider I have already coded, and then make it print the output. For example, if you slide the slider to 45, it will print 45. This is what I have -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

 <div data-role="page">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Choose a Slider Output</h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <form method="post" action="demoform.asp">
      <label for="percentage">Percentage:</label>
      <input type="range" name="percentage" id="percentage" value="50" min="1" max="100">
      <input type="submit" data-inline="true" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
var sliderValue;
$(function () {
   $("#percentage").on("slidestop", function () {
     sliderValue =  $(this).val();
   })
   $("#percentage").on("change", function () {
     sliderValue =  $(this).val();
   })
});

<document.getElementById("print2").innerHTML = sliderValue>

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Although, it doesn't print anything. Please help me by telling me what's wrong. Thank You!

Comment: The code is incorrect. Use `$('#print2').html(sliderValue);`. This will print the value only once. Move the same statement in `change` handler to print the value each time value is changed.

Comment: Where do I put this code

Comment: You've to put the code in both the event handlers at the end.